# Building object using javascript instead of php

Tags: javascript, php

I’m trying to create a data object in javascript that matches the construction from the php script below and need help with adding the ‘depends’ elements under object ‘name’.

```
var data = [{}];
var json = [
{ "type": "type1", "group": "group1", "name": "name1", "depends": ["x","y","z"] },
{ "type": "type2", "group": "group2", "name": "name2", "depends": ["a","b","c"] },
{ "type": "type3", "group": "group3", "name": "name3", "depends": ["q"] }]

json.forEach(function (item) {
    data.push(item.name);
});


json.forEach(function (item) {
    item.forEach(function (item.depends) {
        data.push(item.depends);
    });
});
```

PHP

```
foreach ($json as $obj) {
    $data[$obj['name']] = $obj;
}

foreach ($data as &$obj) {
    $obj['dependedOnBy'] = array();
}

unset($obj);
foreach ($data as &$obj) {
    foreach ($obj['depends'] as $name) {
        if ($data[$name]) {
            $data[$name]['dependedOnBy'][] = $obj['name'];
        } else {
            $errors[] = "Unrecognized dependency: '$obj[name]' depends on '$name'";
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `function (item.depends) {`?. That's not even valid syntax...

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, this is what your php code does:

```
var data = {};
json.forEach(function (item) {
    item.dependedOnBy = [];
    data[item.name] = item;
});

var errors = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (name) {
    data[name].depends.forEach(function (dep) {
        if(!data[dep])
            errors.push( "Unrecognized dependency: " + name + " depends on " + dep);
        else
            data[name].dependedOnBy.push(data[dep]);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yqqdr5bt/

Comment: So I'm not the only one using `Object.keys(data).forEach()`, nice!

Comment: Fantastic.  I'm still on a steep learning curve!   Any ideas why the output doesn't quite match the structure from the php code with json below?


javascript
object {name1: Object, name2: Object, x: Object, y:Object, a: Object...}

php
Object {data: Object, errors: Array[0]}

Comment: @user3359706: the output doesn't match your example, could you edit the post and add some real data? Also, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` instead of just `console.log`.

Comment: Sorry I should have included this:  var json = [
 { "type": "type1", "group": "group1", "name": "name1", "depends": ["x","y"] },
 { "type": "type2", "group": "group2", "name": "name2", "depends": ["a","b"] },
 { "type": "type3", "group": "group3", "name": "x", "depends": [] },
 { "type": "type3", "group": "group3", "name": "y", "depends": [] },
 { "type": "type3", "group": "group3", "name": "a", "depends": [] },
 { "type": "type3", "group": "group3", "name": "b", "depends": [] }
 ]

And I missed this.

echo json_encode(array(
'data'   => $data,
    'errors' => $errors

Comment: @user3359706: see the fiddle.

Comment: I've detected an issue with the levels in the new object.   dependedOnBy has objects but should be the same level as depends.  Any ideas why?



dependedOnBy: Array[2]
0: object
1: object


depends: Array[2]
0: "name1"
1: "name2"